# Lambda query translate .count as select rows (EF6 code first)

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 simple tables.

Post is the master and has n votes. I want to return posts with their vote count. 
This is my code:

```
db.posts.Select(p=>
new PostlDto{Title= p.Title, VoteCount= p.Votes.Count})
```

It is ok that I have 1 call to get posts and several calls to get counts. 
**but the problem is that each time it selects the rows instead of counting them** which is a time consuming action.
This is what sql profiler shows me

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
    FROM [dbo].[Votes] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[PostId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=6
```

I also tried to take the count 1 call by including the votes table in base query, but it also take too long because it also returns rows instead of count of them. :|

```
 db.posts
.Include(p=>p.Votes)
.Select(p=>
 new PostlDto{Title= p.Title, VoteCount= p.Votes.Count})
```

This is the query it translates to

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Project1].[Pid] AS [Pid], 
    [Project1].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Votes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[PostId]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

How can I change it to run a simple count instead?! :|

These queries take multiple seconds to run!

Comment: Please do not add the answer to the question.

Comment: @CodyGray, Ok then where to put it? it has been answered by David

Comment: You already commented under David's answer. You might suggest an edit to make the actual solution more clear. In order for that edit to get approved, you'll need to write a very clear edit summary.

Comment: @CodyGray ok, Cool :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something else must be going on.  Compare your code to this non-repro:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Ef6Test
{

    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; } = new HashSet<Vote>();
    }
    public class Vote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Post Post { get; set; }

    }

    public class PostDto
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int VoteCount { get; set; }
    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {


        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }




    }

    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());


            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                db.Database.Initialize(false);

                var posts = db.Posts.Select(p => new PostDto { Title = p.Title, VoteCount = p.Votes.Count }).ToList();



            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title],
    (SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Votes] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Post_Id]) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: The problem was very stupid! I've had a method that I've used to convert my object to DTO, like .select(convert) and it was a pretty simple one. That was the reason for EF to get dumb! :\